# how to express a functional zip in sql

Tags: sql

i have these two tables that correlate, and i basically want to write

```
for r1, r2 in zip(table1, table2):
  ...
```

how do i do this? the existing code in a stored procedure i need to fix in a hurry looks something like this

```
cursor = select ... where table1.x = table2.x; # implied join
for row in cursor:
  ...
```

which is of course logically like two nested for loops. having all sorts of trouble with the existing code when all i want to do is zip the two tables, ordered by the columns they have in column, and then leave the existing logic in place.

Comment: Maybe I've been living under a rock, but I'm not familiar with any zip functionality.  Are you talking about something along these lines?  http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/11/03/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-3-intermezzo-linq-s-new-zip-operator.aspx

Comment: What exactly does "zip" means in SQL? I have never heard of that.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Your select would probably look something like this:

```
select *
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
    on t1.x = t2.x
```

However, I don't know why you need a cursor here. Perhaps you're trying to loop through these? Cursors have to be declared, opened, closed, and deallocated to avoid handle leaks. The syntax may vary from DB to DB. Here's some sample (MS) T-SQL to get you started.

```
declare z_cur cursor for
    select t1.x, t2.y
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
        on t1.x = t2.x

declare @xVal varchar(100)
     , @yVal varchar(100)

open z_cur
fetch next from z_cur into @xVal, @yVal

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    -- do stuff here
    fetch next from z_cur into @xVal, @yVal
end

close z_cur
deallocate z_cur
```